# why does Non negative matrix Factorization decompose a spectrogram into time and frequency component?

Tags: audio, signals, signal-processing, time-frequency, nmf

When i compute NMF over a spectrogram (mag of stft of a signal ) i obtain

```
W,H = NMF(MyStft,r) # where r=2 is the rank
```

**W** and **H** will respectively  contain  the  spectrum  and  the  temporal information.

My question is why? whats the logic behind that

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: STFT is already a time frequency representation, so it's not a surprise that NMF would also yield some time AND frequency content... 
I suggest you read about NMF in music information retrieval context first ([for example](https://musicinformationretrieval.com/nmf.html)), and come back with more precise questions...